# How do I center my content vertically

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, vertical-alignment

How can I get all of the text content (primary concerned with the drop down button and block) vertically centralized here? I tried what I could research for and find online, but I could not get it to produce the results I want visually.

I need to keep width and height as variables, so I can only go with percentages.

I cannot use fixed padding or margins to achieve what I need, tried it, won't look right when page is resized.

I appreciate any guidance I can get here, too new to coding, but I am trying to learn :) such noob lol

Indeed I would love to find a nice way to make it work, and if applicable I would like to replicate the same to center it horizontally, as currently I am using padding for that purpose, but it is not perfect. However, I can live with this because I will have a known maximum width in any case.

```css
 .div1 {
  Height: 100%;
  Width: 100%;
  background-color: D4D4D2;
  opacity: 0.75
 }
 .div1:hover {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.95
 }

    .dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 310px;
    }

    .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 310px;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: none}
    .dropdown-content a:hover {color: white}
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    }
  </style>
```

```html
<div class="div1">
<div class="dropdown">
     <h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
    <p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1 link very  long</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2 medium</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I was able to get the text content centered with 

    `code "<style>
    .hmtl, body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
   }
    </style>"`

but then my full background hover color change effect is gone and only occurs in the central area surrounding the text. I need to centralize this stuff just like this addition does it, without losing any of the original functionality or visual effects. Full page hover change color of background needs to stay.

Answer (score 0):

ok, trial and error is the way to go when in rush :D

so, after posting this and refusing to give up, despite my broken and fragmented understanding and very little time facing down on my needs, I was able to get exactly what I wanted somehow in the end through trial and error

This code is most def not perfect nor clean, but I hope it helps someone else sometime. Live and learn :D

```css
   .div1 {
  Height: 100%;
  Width: 100%;
  background-color: D4D4D2;
  opacity: 0.75
  }

   .div1:hover {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.95
 }

    .center-block {
      top:50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      position: absolute;
      }

    .dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    padding: 2px 14px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 310px;
    }

    .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 310px;
    }
 
    .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    padding: 2px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: none}
    .dropdown-content a:hover {color: white}
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="div1">
    <div class="center-block">
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1 link very  long</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2 medium</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're after (still needs some tweaking though). I added a height of 100% to the html & body tag and vertically centered the content with the class .center-vertical. This solution is used most of the time if you want to vertically center content, so it would be good to remember this :)

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.div1 {
  Height: 100%;
  Width: 100%;
  background-color: #D4D4D2;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.div1:hover {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.95;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  padding: 2px 14px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 310px;
}
.dropdown {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  min-width: 310px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: none
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  color: white
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
}
.center-vertical {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="dropdown ">
    <h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
    <p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

    <div class="dropdown center-vertical">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1 link very  long</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2 medium</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
#div1{
  justify-content: center;
}
#div2{
  align-items: center;
}
#div3{
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  Horizontally centered
</div>
<div id="div2">
  Vertically centered
</div>
<div id="div3">
  Both Horizontally & Vertically centered
</div>
```

Comment: Great it helped, if you problem is solved accept the answer and you can up vote it for future reference.

Comment: I did upvote, but it does not take, too noob for it lol. How do I "accept" the answer? I cannot seem to find such an "accept answer" button or link no matter where I looked.

Comment: just place your cursor below the vote, you will find a green tick mark. click that. thats it